# Why does the FOR Clause not work with an alias in SQL Server 2016 with temporal tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal-database

I have a SQL Server 2016 database with temporal tables.  One temporal table is called Company.  I am trying to query it to get current records and all historical records.  I first tried the following query:

```
select *
from Company c
FOR SYSTEM_TIME all
```

and got the following error:
**Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'.**

However, if I try it without the alias it works fine:

```
select *
from Company
FOR SYSTEM_TIME all
```

I could not find any documentation about this- is it a legitimate constraint, a known issue, or something else?

Comment: did you try it with an AS? Usually SQL Server implies this and it's optional but i'm wondering if it has to be explicit here.

Comment: Tried with AS, with the same result.

Comment: Seems to be a limitation - But you can use CTE:   .....  WITH _data AS  { SELECT * FROM Company FOR SYSTEM_TIME all }  SELECT * FROM _data AS d .  - see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45144816/495157

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me

```
select *
from Company FOR SYSTEM_TIME all c
```